SpringBoot Upgrade from 2.1.x to 2.2.x or higher versions throwing an error while running ./gradlew build
Failing with below error while upgrading to spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.2.13.RELEASE
bootBuildInfo'.
Unable to find method ''java.util.Properties org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createSortedProperties(boolean)''
We tried to force springframework dependencies to 5.3.13 which was working with springboot 2.1.x bu t it doesn't solve the error
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.13'
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.13'
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.13'
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.13'
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-expression:5.3.13'


this is not a stack trace.  Please put the complete error

I assume you have a good reason to do this, but Spring Boot 2.2 has been out of support for several years now. Also, what is the complete error?

@JCompetence, this is the only error I am seeing even if run with  —stacktrace or —info or —debug

@RolandWeisleder, actually we are trying to migrate to 3.x , since we are seeing this error with 3.x version, tried to increment the version to 2.2.x and this is the only error which is getting printed while running gradle build or bootrun

If your objective is to migrate to 3.x I would recommend doing so and figuring out the errors for it. You are basically wasting your time trying to make a version that should not be the targeted one to work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
